# add_action( 'publish_pelicula', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 ); does not trigger propperly

Tags: actions, wp-mail

I'm trying to send an Email before a post "type:pelicula" is submited, but it does not enter to the function **post_published_notification**, here is the code:

```
<?php

/**
* Plugin Name: VRlife Alertas Publicaciones
* Description: Avisa por el correo configurado al publicar un nuevo video
* Version: 1.0.0
* Author: José Manuel Lascasas
**/

//1
class MySettingsPage
{

    /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //2
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        //6
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
        add_action( 'publish_pelicula', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
    }


    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    //3
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', 
            'My Settings', 
            'manage_options', 
            'my-setting-admin',
            //4 
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    //5
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>My Settings</h1>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'my-setting-admin' );
                submit_button();
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    //7
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'my_option_name', // Option name
            //8
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );
        //10
        add_settings_section(
            'setting_section_id', // ID
            'My Custom Settings', // Title
            //11
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'my-setting-admin' // Page
        );  
        //13
        add_settings_field(
            'title', 
            'Mails',
            //14 
            array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
            'my-setting-admin',
            'setting_section_id'
        );      
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    //9
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();

        if( isset( $input['title'] ) )
            $new_input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

        return $new_input;
    }

    /** 
     * Print the Section text
     */
    //12
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Enter your settings below:';
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    //15
    public function title_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['title']) : ''

        );

        $maill=$this->options['title'];
        //wp_mail( $maill, "wdaawddwwa", "Easy", "" );

    }

    public function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
        $author = $post->post_author; /* Post author ID. */
        $name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );
        $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author );
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $permalink = get_permalink( $ID );
        $edit = get_edit_post_link( $ID, '' );
        $to[] = $this->options['title'];
        $subject = sprintf( 'Published: %s', $title );
        $message = sprintf ('Congratulations, %s! Your article “%s” has been published.' . "\n\n", $name, $title );
        $message .= sprintf( 'View: %s', $permalink );
        $headers[] = '';
        var_dump("hola");
        wp_mail( $to, "wdwadwad", "dwwdawddw", "" );
    }



}
//16
$my_settings_page = new MySettingsPage();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well let's compare the hook to one that is working:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
add_action( 'publish_pelicula', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

`page_init()` and `post_published_notification()` are both methods of the `MySettingsPage` class, but you've set the action callbacks for each of them differently.

The second argument for `add_action()` is a [*callback*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). It tells WordPress/PHP which function to run when the action is fired. For an action to call a class method, you need to pass an array:

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an
>   object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

Since you're running `add_action` inside a class, the object in question is `$this`, and the method name is `post_published_notification`. You've done this correctly for `page_init`, so you just need to do that same for `post_published_notification`:

```
add_action( 'publish_pelicula', array( $this, 'post_published_notification' ), 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a class, you need to specify that the function you want ("post_published_notification") is a part of that class.

You do this by specifying the class before the function as part of an array. It would look like this:

`add_action( 'publish_pelicula', array( $this, 'post_published_notification' ), 10, 2 );`